# Docx file is locked for editing

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am using the python-docx library to make docx files and then later print them to PDF's.  Normally, i use  `os.remove(file_path)`
to get rid of the docx files created during the process.  If I do not destroy these files and then run the script again, I get an error because the file is locked for editing.  I'm trying to understand what is happening here and what the proper protocol is for dealing with these intermediate files.

Any help would be appreciated.

The script generates a docx file called Example.docx and then converts the docx file to a pdf.  If I destroy the docx file, I can run the script again with no problem.  If I do not destroy Example.docx, I get this error:  `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Example.docx'`
I'm trying to understand why this is occurring.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: generally, store those files as temporary file, check out the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) module.